# Looking for a bijective nowhere-continuous function ${\mathbb R}\rightarrow{\mathbb R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Does there exist a bijective function $f:{\mathbb R}\rightarrow{\mathbb R}$ that is nowhere-continuous, assuming that both domain and range have the "standard topology"? <sup>1</sup>

<sub><sup>1</sup> By this I mean the one generated by the open intervals $(a, b) \subset {\mathrm R}$.  BTW, if this topology has a name more readily recognized than *the standard topology* (*on* ${\mathbb R}$), please toss me a comment!</sub>

EDIT: the original version of this question allowed for the possibility that $f$ be only injective, but shortly after I posted the following injective function came to mind: let $n:{\mathbb Q}\rightarrow {\mathbb N}$ be an ordering of the rationals, and define

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} n(x) & x\in\mathbb Q\\ x& x\notin\mathbb Q\end{cases}$$

It is clear that this $f$ is injective, and it seems to me that the proof of the nowhere-continuity of the [Dirichlet function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function) applies to this case as well.

EDIT2: OK, I was next going to try modifying the candidate above to make the function bijective, but Asaf Karagila got there first, with a much neater solution than what I was heading for...

Comment: You can call the topology the *euclidean topology*, because it's induced by the euclidean metric $d(x,y) = |x-y|$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about: $$f(x)=\begin{cases} x+1 & x\in\mathbb Q\\ x& x\notin\mathbb Q\end{cases}$$

Comment: Nice, thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

This function should work.

$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{if x $\in \mathbf{Q}$ and $x \neq 0$} \\
-x & \text{if x $\in \mathbf{R-Q}$}\\
\sqrt{2} & \text{if $ x = 0 $} \end{cases}$

You can find more counterexaples of this type in "Counterexamples in analysis" by Gelbaum and Holmsted.

By the way, as far as I know, the standard topology on $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ is usually called "euclidean topology"

Comment: Not a bijection, $f(0)=f(-\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: does not the case $x\in\mathbb Q$ include $x=0$?

Comment: You are both right: I edited the answer including $x \in \mathbf{Q}$ and $x \neq 0$. By the way @Asaf example is really nice, instead my function works for $x \geq 0 $